# listen for data on tcp/Ip port which is used by another application C#

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I am using HyperEngine which is streaming data on ip 127.0.0.1 and port 8778.

I want to continuously listen on this ip and port. I can't figure out how should I write port listener for this scenario.

Comment: You can't listen on the same port twice - if you could, what purpose would ports serve?

Comment: i just want to connect to that port so i can get the data which is sent on that port.(just like how a server and client application works.sever transmits data on a port and client connect to that port and listens on it.)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the below suggestion works for you.

1. Stop the HeyperEngine service or application.
2. Create a new application which listens to port 8778 on your local
   system.
3. This new application should process the steam data on port 8778
   (the way you want to process) and also publish it to another port.
4. Change the port number of your HyperEngine to the port in which
       you published the steam from your new application.
5. Start the HeyperEngine service or application.

Note: this solution will work, if you have option to change the HyperEngine port configuration.